# Highcharts => Getting the id of a point when clicking on a line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am building a line chart and I would like, when I click on a point of the line, to display a popup containing some data about this point.
The issue I try to resolve is to get the id, the series associated with this point or something like that.

Here is my code :

```
plotOptions: {
      column: {
        pointWidth: 20
      },

      series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        events: {
          click: function(event) {
            requestData(event.point);
          }
        }
      }
```

I tried

```
requestData(this.point)
```

,

```
requestData(this.point.id)
```

also but it doesn't work.

How do we get the id of a point ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 16):

According to the docs, *event.point holds a pointer to the nearest point on the graph*.

So I'd write the `event.point` to the console, and see what's available.

```
console.log(event.point);
```

[From the docs:](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-series-events)

> click: Fires when the series is clicked. The this keyword refers to the series object itself. One parameter, event, is passed to the function. This contains common event information based on jQuery or MooTools depending on which library is used as the base for Highcharts. Additionally, event.point holds a pointer to the nearest point on the graph.

**Example based on the example from the docs:** http://jsfiddle.net/5nTYd/

Click a point, and check the console.

Comment: @Johann - I updated my answer. Log `event.point` to the console to see what properties are available to you from the nearest `point` that was clicked.

Comment: Here is what I obtain in my console :

Processing ChartsController#return_data (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-08-19 13:10:36) [GET]
  Parameters: {"name"=>"[object Object]", "_"=>"1282248635940"}

Comment: event.point is just an [object Object] and it doesn't say what properties are available...

Comment: What browser are you using? You should be able to expand the `Object` to see all its properties. In Safari/Chrome or Firebug dev tools, you click the `Object` in the console. If you're using IE8, I'm not sure. If you're doing an `alert()` then you'll just get `[object Object]`. If that's the case, I'd recommend using developer tools instead.

Answer (score 11):

I just did this by passing 3 objects into the series data array and then pulling it out of the object's config attribute from the click.

So you can construct your series data something like this:

```
 series: [{
  name: 'Example',
  yAxis: 0,
  type: 'spline',
  data: [[1294099200000,220.0,37],[1296432000000,190.0,40],[1297036800000,184.4,5]]
}]
```

In the data attribute above the 1st element is the date (x), the 2nd element is another data point (y), and the 3rd is the id of the object that represent that data object.  This "z" will not show up on the graph but will show up as the 3rd element in the config array.  For example: using plotOptions point attribute to capture the click, the ID of the object is in the alert as this.config[2]

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      cursor: 'pointer',
      point: {events: {click: function() {console.log(this); alert('Category: '+ this.category +', value: '+ this.y + 'Series: ' +  this.series.name + ' ID: ' + this.config[2])}}}
     }
   },
```

Answer (score 3):

To return the 'ID' of the selected point on the chart use the 'X' value:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        events: {
            click: function(event) {
                   // Log to console
                console.log(event.point);
                alert(this.name +' clicked\n'+
                      'Alt: '+ event.altKey +'\n'+
                      'Control: '+ event.ctrlKey +'\n'+
                      'Shift: '+ event.shiftKey +'\n'+
                      'Index: '+ event.point.x);
            }
        }
    }
},
```

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/engemasa/mxRwg/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem ... if I understand correctly.
My solution is this, to get the id of the series ...
See if it helps ...

```
plotOptions{
 series:{
  cursor: 'pointer',
    events: {
      click: function(event) {
        console.log(event.point.series.userOptions.id);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Saved me a great time.

Answer (score 0):

i found this old post in my search to ==>add a marker to a point when i click a Highcharts "Trend Line" [in examples: "line-time-series"] chart[when i click anywhere on the drawn line itself]. well, without showing you too much code, look in the

```
  cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                      events: {
                             click: function(e) {
                                alert("X("+this.x+"),Y("+this.y+")");
                                }//click
                          }//events
                           }//point
```

if you would like more detail, i'm happy to provide!

Answer (score 0):

```
 plotOptions: {
   series: {
     cursor: 'pointer',
     point: {
       events: {
         click: function() {
           console.log(this); 
           alert('Category: '+ this.category +', value: '+ this.y + 'Series: ' +  this.series.name + ' ID: ' + this.config[2])
         }
       }
     }
   }
 },
```