# Highcharts get selected column index

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a column chart and I would like to be able to assign a click event which would fire a window.open() to a dynamically generated URL. I have an array that contains the elements for the x-Axis which I can use to generate the URL for the window.open() if I can get a pointer to the selected column. Below is the code for the chart.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'column',
            margin: [50, 50, 350, 50]
        },

        title: {
            text: 'E-Tags Cause'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: _MyArray2,
            labels: {
                rotation: 45,
                align: 'left',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '18px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Count'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                events: {
                    click: function (event) {
                        window.open('test' +  + '.html');
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'E-Tag Count',
            data: _MyArray,
            pointWidth: 40,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: 0,
                color: '#000000',
                align: 'center',
                x: -3,
                y: -2,
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.y;
                },
                style: {
                    fontSize: '14px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        }]
    });
    $('tspan').last().remove();
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Highcharts, but check out this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524774/highcharts-getting-the-id-of-a-point-when-clicking-on-a-line-chart Calling `console.log` on the `event` object and `this` that are available in the click handler seems like a good place to start.

Comment: This also might be relevant, from the docs: _Click: Fires when the series is clicked. The this keyword refers to the series object itself. One parameter, event, is passed to the function. This contains common event information based on jQuery or MooTools depending on which library is used as the base for Highcharts. Additionally, event.point holds a pointer to the nearest point on the graph._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

**ADD** the `point` object after column

[WORKING JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/szTzH/1/)

```
   $(function() {
      chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

          chart: {
              renderTo: 'container',
              defaultSeriesType: 'column'
          },

          title: {
              text: ''
          },

          xAxis: {
              categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May',
                      'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
          },

          plotOptions: {
              column :{
                  point:{
                      events:{
                          click:function(){
                            window.open(this.x + '.html') ;
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          },

          series: [{
              data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 
                   135.6, 148.5, 216.4,     194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
               }],

              navigation: {
                  buttonOptions: {
                      align: 'center'
                  }
              }
          });




      });​
```

Comment: There is already a click even for the column itself. I was looking for a method of generating the URL for the window.open(URL) when that chart loads.

Comment: are you trying to find a way to fire a function on chart load complete ?

Comment: No. So I would like to assign a window.open(someURL) to the click event of each column when the chart is created. that URL should be created using the x-Axis array. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: if you need to get hold to the xAxis value to the clicked point use this.x

Comment: I see where my issue was. Thank you!