# How do I get the value of a highcharts graph point on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am creating a highcharts chart series using the following logic:

```
this.series = [];

for(var i in headerData) {
    var header = headerData[i];

    this.series.push({
        name: header.name,
        data:[],
        yAxis:parseInt(header.axis),
        id: header.id,
        type: 'column',
        zIndex: 1,
        events: {
            mouseOver: function (e) {
                console.log('Point: ', e.point);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524774/highcharts-getting-the-id-of-a-point-when-clicking-on-a-line-chart) that the point is a property of the event `e`, but in my case `e.point` is `undefined`. I also cannot find anything in `e` related to the moused-over point.

Does anybody know how to get the x- and y-values of the point that has been moused over?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the `event` on the `plotOptions` property. Here's an example taken from the `Highcharts` API documentation:

```
$(function () {
    var $reporting = $('#reporting');

    $('#container').highcharts({

        title: {
            text: 'Mouse events demo'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'On point mouse over or mouse out, the values should be reported in top left'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                point: {
                    events: {
                        mouseOver: function () {
                            var chart = this.series.chart;
                            if (!chart.lbl) {
                                chart.lbl = chart.renderer.label('')
                                    .attr({
                                        padding: 10,
                                        r: 10,
                                        fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                                    })
                                    .css({
                                        color: '#FFFFFF'
                                    })
                                    .add();
                            }
                            chart.lbl
                                .show()
                                .attr({ 
                                    text: 'x: ' + this.x + ', y: ' + this.y 
                                });
                        }
                    }
                },
                events: {
                    mouseOut: function () {
                        if (this.chart.lbl) {
                            this.chart.lbl.hide();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/a145td6c/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `chart.hoverPoint` if trying to find out the currently moused over point from outside the `mouseOver` event. However this is not on the documentation, which likely means it can change in the future.